# ServletContext attribute is null

Tags: java, servlets

The attribute `repository` returns `null`.

```
public class BaseServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected MyPersistentManager getPersistentManager(){
        return (MyPersistentManager) getServletContext().getAttribute("repository");
    }
//...
}
```

I am setting it here:

```
public class ServletListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        /*
        load data
         */
        ServletContext servletContext = sce.getServletContext();
        MyPersistentManager persistentManager = new MyPersistentManager();
        servletContext.setAttribute("repository", persistentManager);
    }
}
```

Why is it not been set? It seems like that context isn't initialized? I tried to reset Tomcat, but that didn't solve the problem. I am using Netbeans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the ServletListener class registered in web.xml?

```
<listener>
 <listener-class>mypackage.ServletListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

From the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html): *"Implementations of this interface receive notifications about changes to the servlet context of the web application they are part of. **To receive notification events, the implementation class must be configured in the deployment descriptor for the web application.** "*

Comment: Yes. I've added the relevant documentation link.